# localStorage between panel content script and page content script in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating a firefox addon with addon builder, and I want to save a value from page content, and then read it from panel content script. I want to use localStorage, but I tried and I cannot share the same localStorage between page and panel script. Also I tried with self.port.emit , and this method is working perfectly I can send the value with port.emit and port.on, but this is not what i want because I need to refresh this value every second, and if I use that method then browser is overloaded with port requests, and that's why I want to use localStorage or something which can be stored in a variable and easily accessed from panel script.

here I'm attaching panel script, which will read the value saved with page script.

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          contentScriptFile: data.url("panel_script.js")
    });
```

here I'm attaching page script which will save a value from page content and panel script will read it.

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("page_script.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready'
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `port` system is the recommended route for interacting with a Panel page. However here's how you'd solve the problem you've posted of accessing `localStorage` for a page via a Firefox add-on.

```
var chrome = require('chrome');
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

var ios = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                .getService(chrome.Ci.nsIIOService);
var ssm = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"]
                .getService(chrome.Ci.nsIScriptSecurityManager);
var dsm = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/dom/storagemanager;1"]
                .getService(chrome.Ci.nsIDOMStorageManager);

var uri = ios.newURI(data.url('index.html'), "", null);
var principal = ssm.getCodebasePrincipal(uri);
var storage = dsm.getLocalStorageForPrincipal(principal, data.url('index.html'));
```

With that you'll be able to access the page's `localStorage` using the `storage` object as you normally would in a web page.  e.g. `storage.setItem('key', 'value')` and `storage.getItem('key')`.

Comment: Your answer is close to what i need, but not exaclty. I want to access storage object from panel_script.js which i have posted in above code. If you show me how to access from panel_script.js then I will consider your answer as accepted 100%. Thank you for your help so far I find your answer helpful for my future works. Please if you have an idea how to access storage object from panel script (not main.js) then I'm very happy

Comment: It won't be able to access the same localStorage that your page_script is working with because it's hooked to a different domain.  The only way I know to avert that is through direct add-on access like I've shown.  Your add-on can watch the pageMod localStorage for events and then write to your panel localStorage.  That's about the only way I see that working.  Good Luck!

Comment: ok, you said "add-on can watch the pageMod localStorage for events and then write to your panel localStorage".. so this is what i need, but how to do that, without sending port requests. Because I'm refreshing this value in a timer and I want to make it faster to refresh using mileseconds interval. If for that interval I will send many port requests then browser is overloading, because it is sending/receiving port requests. Do you have an idea how to make this value available for panel script to access it from a location or anything which will make the browser not to overload

Comment: Nit: De-structuring is more idiomatic: var { Cc, Cu, Ci } = require("chrome"); ...even though it is odd-looking to web developers at first.

Comment: You could add an `onAttach` handler to your pageMod which would let you know when it attaches to a new page/domain.  Inside that onAttach function you run the code that I provided above to listen for changes to the localStorage in that page you are attached to.  As you received those page localStorage changes you write to your Panel local storage using similar code as I provided above.  With that system your Panel would just watch for localStorage changes being written from the add-on code.  @canuckistani I like to use jslint which doesn't accept the non-standard deconstructors. :-\

Comment: *jshint* is getting patched for Moz JS I hear :D